# How to represent small numbers in academic writing?

Tags: tables, formatting, statistics, mathematics

I am seeking some suggestions through this query. In case this is not the right forum, kindly suggest where I may get an answer?

I need to represent small numbers in multiple tables meant for scientific publication. I am wondering which is the preferred way: 1.235e-3, or 1.235x10^-3?

The issue is that the latter format requires more width than the former. Hence, most of the tables may extend the page width.

Comment: Maybe ask at https://academia.stackexchange.com

Comment: If all numbers in a column share the same magnitude, you could place this information in the column header in oder to save some space.

Answer (score 1):

Use the package `siunitx`. It offers a *lot* of options to format numbers (and also quantities with dimensions).